# How to connect my postgresql database with my django project?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

When I run the command "pg_ctl -D  -l logfile start", I have this result :

waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output

And when I ckecked the logs, I have this :
[check-logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l29E6.png)

And this is my configuration:
[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rZC9.png)
[postgresql.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUC5U.png)
[pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojN2r.png)

Do I change the .conf files ? And which parameters ?
Thank you for you answers !

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with Django. You're not able to start Postgres itself.

Comment: From your log file, it appears that postgres is already running.  Can you see it in the process list?

Comment: Yes, I saw "postregres.exe", "pgadmin4.exe" and "pg_ctl.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use:

```
{
   "HOST": "0.0.0.0"
}
```

Or if you using the docker:

```
{
   "HOST": "contanter name"
}
```